# Variable set to null in JSON StringBuffer, Android Studio

Tags: json, android-studio

I encounter a very strange problem. I familiarize myself with json strings. I have the following code in android studio.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
String tmp="";
while((tmp=reader.readLine())!=null) {
    tmp = reader.readLine();
    if (tmp != null) {
        String test = tmp;
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

In the debugger the line `tmp = reader.readLine();` shows me the json string that i should take, but as soon as i continue my program the tmp variable sets to null and the test variable never gets the desired value. Any idea what I am doing wrong..? Thank you very much in advance..!

Comment: You are assigning value to tmp variable twice, one in while condition and other inside the condition. Use reader.readLine() instead of tmp = reader.readLine() in while condition

Comment: I tried it and now the tmp variable is always null...

Comment: sorry my bad, your while condition is ok, just remove the 
tmp = reader.readline() from inside the condition.